# How much time should I account to spend on the Keukenhof?

Tags: planning, netherlands

I am planning a day trip to the Keukenhof in the Netherlands. From my reading I understand that that must be really busy. They even have a fast lane to enter. I assume that if you have a normal ticket you should prepare to wait.

I am trying to plan a day trip there (with possibly some other stops in the Netherlands) but I would like to know how much time I should account to realistically visit+wait in the queue. Does anyone have experience with this?

I know this may vary from weekday to weekend. The time one can spend on the garden also depends on how fast you walk, of course. But I am sure there is an average.

[image]

Comment: I got the advice to buy the tickets in Schiphol Airport. This way you can skip the queue in the counters of Keukenhof.

Comment: Wow, someone got **WAY** too carried away with the filters in that picture.

Comment: @CMaster the smoke of some species must have affected the camera :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not *that* bad, coming around midday and spending a few hours is perfectly doable. There will be some waiting at the entrance and a lot of walking but you can see a lot in, say, 3 hours. To give you a baseline, I have been to both type of attractions several times and often waited much longer at Amsterdam's main museums. Buying the tickets online can also make thing easier and save some time.

If you really want to see everything, you could also probably spend the full day there, coming early to avoid the bulk of the traffic around the area. The park itself also includes a few restaurants and is obviously keen on having people spend more money there but I typically don't stay that long and still manage to see quite a lot. Usually, my guests are quite exhausted by all the driving and walking and I don't plan any other visit for the day.

What you *shouldn't* expect is being able to drive there, park close to the entrance, get a ticket in a couple of min and be in and out in one hour. You wouldn't see much and spend a lot of money for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The garden is huge and I spent more than 3 hours inside because I wanted to see everything. You can skip the ticket queue by buying your ticket online. The problem with a day trip is only the drive to the place. It took me longer than it should have been because of the heavy traffic once I was almost there. But a day trip is still doable, especially if you don't plan to see the flower parade on the same day.
As with your plan to make some stops in the Netherlands, I wouldn't recommend it unless you just want to see the cities at night.

Comment: +1 Good point about the traffic, there is often some traffic jams on the way to the car park.

Comment: For me, it was on the highway going to Lisse. We parked on the neighbourhood to avoid further traffic jams, and of course get free parking spot ;)

Answer (score 3):

Living close to the Keukenhof I would suggest you come early in the morning, spend as much time in the garden as you like, and then check all of the flower fields around the Keukenhof. A full day should be enough even on busy days.

Answer (score 3):

One day seems reasonable, but if you get bored easily, you can spend only half a day. It is very beautiful in Keukenhof, and not too crowded to enjoy the view. No, the line was not too long when we visited.

One day seems a bit of a stretch though, depending on what time you want to get there. 3/4 is more like it, but it depends on a person.

Comment: could you describe a bit more why half a day or why a full day? Like the kind of activities for example.

Comment: Full day: walk walk walk in the main part then eat lunch then walk to the windmill

Comment: Half a day: same thing but skip some of the pavilions and not stay for too long at the windmill

Comment: http://www.travelx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Keukenhof-Garden-Map2.png

Answer (score 1):

The "fast lane" is for people with prepaid tickets, so if you buy a ticket before you get there you're set. Of course a lot of people do just that so the fast lane at peak times may not be that fast :)

Very early is usually good. Be there just around the time they open if you can. From other tourist attractions in the area (I've not myself visited Keukenhof), busiest times for arrival are typically between 10am and 2 in the afternoon. 
They open at 8 in the morning, so best you be there between 8 and 9. You'll have an hour or two before things get crowded to enjoy the place in relative quiet.
Tickets can be purchased online, saves finding a ticket bureau (and paying their surcharges): http://keukenhof.nl/en/plan-your-visit/tickets/ (but you will need a printer of course to print the tickets).